# MongoDB Transaction, prevent multiple update on multi-server

Tags: node.js, mongodb

On scale-out servers, several servers will compete the update process each other for the multiple data.

So I want to prevent multiple update on the same data.

=Coffee

```
CollectionRooms.find(isProcessed: false).forEach (room) ->
  if room.isProcessed then return
  #update something
  CollectionRooms.update _id: room._id,
    $set: isProcessed: true
```

The question between two servers(SERVER1, SERVER2) with same MongoDB is,

- After the moment of SERVER1's find action,
- If SERVER2 update that data to isProcessed = true,
- Then the data in SERVER1's forEach could be isProcessed true?

I think I need to make the question simple.

- find() will returns the cursor,
- then inside of the loop in .forEach function,
- each loop's actual data is different with find() function started?.

Sorry for ugly expressions and thanks.

Comment: two servers(SERVER1, SERVER2): do you mean 2 processes ?

Comment: possibly 2 processes. but suppose to be separated multi server.

Comment: If the culprit is multiple processes running at the same time, then you may want to find current process's id and allow only one process to execute your query.
in case of pm2: 
if(process.env.NODE_APP_INSTANCE == 0) { //your task }

Answer (score 1):

Use optimistic locking.

Have an additional field on your document (a timestamp, or version number) which is updated every time the document is written. Then use this version in your update queries. The update will fail if the version has changed since reading.

Comment: That would be one of the solution, but I'm not sure that's all. I made my question simplified.